# PHP - see cookies used by a website

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, curl

I am learning PHP and I am in the middle of the creation of a cookie-crawler.

For now, I am using PHPCrawl and I can crawl the website - the problem is that I cannot retrieve the list of the cookies.

I have this, in order to enable the cookie handling:
$crawler->enableCookieHandling(true);

And I know that the Cookies are sent from the page and should be found during the crawling as an object of the class: PHPCrawlerDocumentInfo.

However, now I have no idea on how this cookies object should be retrieved and their value displayed.

My results is to have something like :
-www.cookiebot.com
-www.cookie-checker.com

Some people suggested me to use CURL for that - does anybody have any help who can provide, - a function to write or whatever it can be useful for me?

It would be very helpful since I am stucked!

Thank you.

Comment: To be clear: you want to crawl any website and get back a list of cookies the website has set for your call?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
I really would love to have a similar result to the one of the two website I have sent you.

Basically they give as output a result with all the cookies that are  used.

So for example:
1 cookie and 2 third party cookies, and display simple value such as name, value and expiry date.

That is all I would like to do.

Comment: For third-party cookies, you would not only have to crawl the website itself, but also request every such piece of third-party content. And for cookies set via JS, you would have to execute JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 0):

First I dont think there is anyway around cURL.
Second, this should work just fine:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.de/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/(Set-Cookie:.*)/', $result, $cookies);


foreach($cookies[0] as $cookie) {

    var_dump($cookie);
    preg_match_all('/(.*?)=(.*?)($|;|,(?! ))/', $cookie, $cookieMatch);
    var_dump($cookieMatch);
}
die();
```

Output

```
string 'Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=0565f3cee75e9b3e:FF=0:TM=1406983634:LM=1406983635:S=ilchxFTsUukIvmPn; expires=Mon, 01-Aug-2016 12:47:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.de
' (length=155)

array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=0565f3cee75e9b3e:FF=0:TM=1406983634:LM=1406983635:S=ilchxFTsUukIvmPn;' (length=89)
      1 => string ' expires=Mon, 01-Aug-2016 12:47:15 GMT;' (length=39)
      2 => string ' path=/;' (length=8)
      3 => string ' domain=.google.de
' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Set-Cookie: PREF' (length=16)
      1 => string ' expires' (length=8)
      2 => string ' path' (length=5)
      3 => string ' domain' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'ID=0565f3cee75e9b3e:FF=0:TM=1406983634:LM=1406983635:S=ilchxFTsUukIvmPn' (length=71)
      1 => string 'Mon, 01-Aug-2016 12:47:15 GMT' (length=29)
      2 => string '/' (length=1)
      3 => string '.google.de
' (length=11)
3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string ';' (length=1)
      1 => string ';' (length=1)
      2 => string ';' (length=1)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I saw this part of code already.
I thought anyone had any experience with PHP Crawl - here I think I have to parse the output since it is all "mixed".

Comment: This code above will snip out just the cookies. What you do with the rest is up to you.